# JFrame Image wont appear, require refresh?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am having trouble getting an image to appear at the start of the program. When I run the application the window appears, along with my button. But no image displays, until i re-size the window by expanding the sides. I would like the image to appear on its own

Thank you in advance,

```
  public class Window
  {

    static final String IP_ADDRESS = "http://192.168.1.64/Image.jpg";
    JFrame frame;
    JButton btn1 = new JButton("New Image");
    ImageIcon icon = null;
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
    Camera cam = new Camera();

    Window()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("IP Camera");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700, 700);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame.add(btn1);
        btn1.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());

        icon = new ImageIcon(cam.getImage(IP_ADDRESS));
        label = new JLabel(icon);

        frame.add(label);

    }

    class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getSource() == btn1) {

                frame.remove(label);

                icon = new ImageIcon(cam.getImage(IP_ADDRESS));
                label = new JLabel(icon);
                frame.add(label);

                label.setVisible(true);

                label.repaint();
                frame.repaint();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look where you call `setVisible(true)`. And look where you create your GUI. Shouldn't that be swapped? Shouldn't you make all visible **after** creating the GUI?

Comment: Thank you! It worked for the initial appearance of the image, but after I use the button i have to do the resize trick. could i just  setVisible(true);  again?